# Using CLASID to identifying software Module

Tags: windows, registry

Is there any way of identifying software modules with the help of only knowing CLASID value in the windows registry?

Comment: Do you mean `CLSID`? (No 'A' in usual abbreviation for "class identifier")

Comment: :) yes you are right it is CLSID

Answer (score 0):

If you know the CLSID, you can find the component in the registry, lookup

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<Guid>
```

Where `<guid>` is the CLSID in the braced format used in the registry. Under this key you will get one of several possible keys that will lead to the implementation. E.g. `InProcServer32` for in process. The default value of the GUID key is usually the name of the component, which scripting languages can use to create instances (and appears in `HKCR\` along with file extensions).